# How to Secure a Lucene.Net Index in an ASP.Net MVC Application

Tags: encryption, lucene, asp.net-mvc-5, lucene.net

I created an ASP.Net MVC site and used Lucene.Net to create a searchable index on two integer, three string and two date data fields.  The site is currently hosted on a MS Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  The server will be replaced with a new Windows Server 201X box within the next year.

It all works great, especially after I used some multi-tasking for updating and inserting into the index.

My concern is securing the index.  It contains Last Name, First Name, Middle Name, Date of Birth, Date of Death and Medical Record IDs.  I realize the app_data folder is somewhat secure.  However, if the server is compromised, I would like the index to be very difficult to use.

I'm currently trying out the idea of encrypting the data within the index, which means encrypting inserts/updates, decrypting and displaying the search results, and searching the encrypted data.  I was hoping someone might have a better idea for how to accomplish this.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You do know that would break and wild card searching.   It would also break sort.   Why did you pick Lucene for structured data like that?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  I'm new to this, so I missed the fact that the index is essentially a text file.  I certainly do not have to keep using Lucene.Net.  I would appreciate any suggestions.  I also realize that I may simply end up using a combination of views and LINQ to accomplish this.

Comment: Also, I needed this type of search capability.  The data is not as static with this population as it is with most groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Also, I needed this type of search capability" is not clear.

Update is not efficient in Lucene.

MSSQL you can encrypt a [column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) or entire table or entire database.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected I would probably end up not using Lucene.